# Выбрать максимальные значении из возвращаемого запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос к примеру:

```
SELECT 
       r.[name],  
       Sum(oa.premium) premSum 
       ,(r.[coefficient] * vt.coefficient) as coeff
FROM 
[o_application] oa      
INNER JOIN [vehicle_policy] vp     (nolock) on oa.id = vp.[ogpo_application_id]
INNER JOIN [region_registration] r (nolock) on vp.[region_registration] = r.id
inner join [vehicle_type] vt       (nolock) on vt.id = vp.[vehicle_type]
WHERE 
(oa.policy_date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-06-06') 
and vp.state_number = '123' 
group by  r.[name], r.[coefficient], vt.coefficient, 
vp.state_number
order by coeff
```

Запрос возвращает :

```
name                prem        coef    number
Акмолинская область 52399.00    2,7588  B694WMA
Акмолинская область 14675.00    5,2536  B694WMA
Акмолинская область 12841.00    2,7588  B694WMA
```

Нужно если номера(number) одиноковие то возвращать только одну запись у которого максимальный коэффициент. В данном случае :

```
Акмолинская область 14675.00    5,2536  B694WMA
```

Как выбрать максимальное значение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так подойдёт?

```
select name, premSum, coeff, state_number from (
SELECT 
       r.[name],  
       Sum(oa.premium) premSum 
       ,(r.[coefficient] * vt.coefficient) as coeff
,row_number() over(partition by r.[name], vp.state_number order by r.[coefficient] * vt.coefficient desc) rn
FROM 
[o_application] oa      
INNER JOIN [vehicle_policy] vp     (nolock) on oa.id = vp.[ogpo_application_id]
INNER JOIN [region_registration] r (nolock) on vp.[region_registration] = r.id
inner join [vehicle_type] vt       (nolock) on vt.id = vp.[vehicle_type]
WHERE 
(oa.policy_date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-06-06') 
and vp.state_number = '123' 
group by  r.[name], r.[coefficient], vt.coefficient, 
vp.state_number
) X where rn=1
order by coeff
```

Comment: да, но если в partition by только по vp.state_number

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
       r.[name],  
       Sum(oa.premium) premSum 
       ,(r.[coefficient] * vt.coefficient) as coeff
       ,MAX(r.[coefficient] * vt.coefficient)
       OVER ( PARTITION BY  vp.state_number) as MAXcoeff
FROM 
[o_application] oa      
INNER JOIN [vehicle_policy] vp     (nolock) on oa.id = vp.[ogpo_application_id]
INNER JOIN [region_registration] r (nolock) on vp.[region_registration] = r.id
inner join [vehicle_type] vt       (nolock) on vt.id = vp.[vehicle_type]
WHERE 
(oa.policy_date between '2016-04-01' and '2016-06-06') 
and vp.state_number = '123' 
group by  r.[name], r.[coefficient], vt.coefficient, 
vp.state_number
) q
where q.MAXcoeff = q.coeff
```